# Core Data working without its stack included

Tags: swift, macos, core-data

I encountered a weird situation.

My initial idea was to implement a lightweight migration for my core data model, because it has changed.
Trying to do that, I noticed that I never included the stack in my code (macOS app).

Core Data is working as it should (on El Capitan and above - app not compatible with earlier version)!

My question: how is this possible? How could I investigate this further?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: "the stack"...care to elaborate on which parts aren't being included, rather than just a generic term that could mean many different things? 

Comment: By Core Data stack, I mean : the code that should be added to any app to make it use Core Data. The code that is typically added to `AppDelegate`and that you can find in Apple documentation.

Comment: A "Core Data stack" could also includes all your model classes, the framework, the schema, and any management code you have. Anyway my best bet with 0 posted code is it's probably just running in memory and nothing will be saved.

Comment: Not at all, it's an app that's been running in production for more than a year. As written in my answer below, I remembered in-between that the Core Data stuff was handled in the `NSPersistentDocument` application. I've been mistaken by some article on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Well... the answer is that it is a NSDocument-based application. The Core Data stack is thus NOT added to the AppDelegate. It's likely included in the NSPersistentDocument class.